# Unable to install custom expo client for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am trying to get my React-Native app to run on my iPhone. It uses the expo background location service, and as such I need to use a custom iOS expo client to run the app on my iPhone (as suggested [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/background-location-not-working/23433/3)). I am following [this](https://docs.expo.io/guides/adhoc-builds/) tutorial to install a custom iOS expo client on an iPhone. I have already created the device I want this custom expo client to be installed on in my Apple Developer console. I am running Windows 10 version 1809 on my development computer.

The process works smoothly until I need to select whether I would like to register a new device. I select *No* (n) as my device is already listed, and I get the error:

`? Would you like to register a new device to use the Expo client with? No
Unable to fetch manifest from: https://exp.host/@exponent/home.`

Here is a screenshot of the process:

[expo client:ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5fpI.png)

I have also tried entering *Yes* (Y) and the process works fine until I try to install the profile on my iPhone when I get the message:

```
Waiting for user to register their device for development
```

[iPhone expo notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY3yu.jpg)

Despite the message's implication that an email will arrive detailing the directions to register for UDID (presumably to my expo account email), an email never arrives.

I would expect that when I enter *No* (n) I should get a link and/or QR code to install the client on my device.

I am certain others have also set up a custom expo client for iOS. What could I possibly be doing wrong?